# How to read SignalR messages using Lua inside nginx ingress controller

Tags: lua, signalr, nginx-ingress, signalr-hub

I have a .NET web API server running SignalR behind an Nginx ingress controller.

What I would like to do is, just like other HTTP requests and their payloads, read the messages getting sent back and forth from the SignalR server and the clients.

Can it be done? I can easily read the payload of HTTP requests and log them when I need to, but not certain if a WSS request can also be read like HTTP.

If the answer is a yes, please provide any code samples that accomplish it.